# How to give padding to content inside a outline border

Tags: html, css

Here I want to align this inside circle at the left border. As shown in the image by orange lines.
Here is my HTML code for this

```
<section style="height: 300px;border: 2px solid green;">
        <ul id="Name_Section">
            <li style=" border: 2px solid blue;">I AM PRAVEEN KUMAR </li>
            <li id="logo"></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Below is the CSS for this.
Ignore the extra code if there it is.
[image]

```
#Name_Section{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 30px;
}
#Name_Section li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
#logo{
    outline: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    outline-offset: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(38, 38, 54);
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two container for you to reproduce the effect you desire, basically the outer container should have a white border, the inside container containing the text should have a smaller dimension than the outer container. In my example there's a `2em` height and width difference to achieve the effect. Both then sould have `display: flex;`, `align-items` and `justify-content` set to center, to align the items inside of them to the center. See the snippet below for your reference.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background: #4A495B;
}

#Name_Section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.outside {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 12em;
  width: 12em;
}

.inside{
  background: #272636;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul id="Name_Section">
    <li class="outside">
      <p class="inside">I AM PRAVEEN KUMAR </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

place the element inside a parent div that own the size, the padding and the border

- the parent have a relative position
- the logo have an absolute position

you can now move the child where you want in the parent with properties top, bottom, left or right

```css
#logo{
    background-color: rgb(38, 38, 54);
    border-radius: 70px;
    height: calc(100% - 14px);
    width: calc(100% - 14px);
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:7px; //the midle of the parent padding
}

.element-border {
  position:relative;
  border: solid grey 1px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  padding: 14px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="element-border">
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </div>
```